# How to setup a Docker Compose script to emulate Heroku's Celadon Cedar-14 for resurrecting an old Rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, heroku, rubygems

I've got a scenario where I have to bring an old Ruby on Rails 3 app back to life that took its last breaths on Cedar-14 (which [was Ubuntu 14.04](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-14-stack) I believe) on Heroku some time ago.

The goal is to rebuild an environment that is as close as possible to the old system so that I can run this for some months while some work towards a rebuild take place.

The requirements are for it to have:

- Ruby `1.9.3-p551`
- Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '~> 3.0.10'
gem "paperclip", "2.3.8"
gem "rmagick", "2.13.4"
gem "acts_as_list", "~> 0.1.4"
gem "aws-ses", :require => "aws/ses"
gem "ffaker"
gem "validates_timeliness", "3.0.13"
gem "date_validator"  
gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3' 
gem 'airbrake'
gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rack-attack'
gem 'rails_12factor'
```

Perhaps also of interest is the lock file: [Gist for Gemfile.lock](https://gist.github.com/ylluminate/0fe06f5f18378032e1962bebcc396706)

I'd like to get some specific instructions on how to pull together such a Compose file for, what appears, Ubuntu 14.04 with all the accompanying requirements from the above.

It also appears that it may be possible to incorporate this Docker image somehow into the Compose script from Heroku, but I am slightly leery of it since it's untouched now itself as well for some time and I'd hate for it to vanish somehow. Also, Ubuntu's Extendend Security Maintenance agreement scheme forbids updates to be published, so it would probably be better to run my own updated version instead of this: https://hub.docker.com/r/heroku/cedar/

For what it's worth, the database was changed and it's using a current version of MySQL/MariaDB no in terms of where the database is stored, so I don't actually require a database server - only to give it database connection details in the environment + S3 access.